# Bash script cut at specific ranges

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file with a plenty of collected logs, I already made a `grep` command with a regex that outputs the number of lines that matches it.
This is the `grep` command I'm using to output the matched lines:

```
grep -n -E 'START_REGEX|END_REGEX' Example.log | cut -d ':' -f 1 > ranges.txt
```

The regex is conditional it can match the begin of a specific log or its end, thus the output is something like:

```
12
45
128
136
...
```

The idea is to use this as a source of ranges to make specific cut on the log file from first number to the second and save them on another file.
The ranges are made by couples of the output, according to the example the first range is `12,45` and the second `128,136`.
I expect to see in the final file all the text from line `12 to 45` and then from `128 to 136`.
The problem I'm facing is that the `sed` command seems to work with only one range at time.

```
sed -E -iTMP "$START_RANGE,$END_RANGE! d;$END_RANGEq" $FILE_NAME
```

Is there any way (maybe with `awk`) to do that just in one "cycle"?
Constraints: I can only use supported bash command.

Comment: Please clarify what constitutes a range from the source and also give example input and output.

Comment: What did you actually try to do in the first place, before thinking of the elaborate grep?

Comment: Thank you I updated the answer.

Comment: Note that you could do the whole thing in one `awk` or `sed` command. Search for `sed/awk multiline matching`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` you can do multiple ranges of lines like so:

```
sed -n '12,45p;128,136p'
```

This would output lines 12-45, then 128-136.

Comment: Yep is working!! When I was trying using multiple ranges I was missing the `p`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `awk` statement, too

```
awk '(NR>=12 && NR<=45) || (NR>=128 && NR<=136)' file
```

where, `NR` is a special variable in `Awk` which keep tracks of the line number as it processes the file.

An example,

```
seq 1 10 > file
cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
awk '(NR>=1 && NR<=3) || (NR>=8 && NR<=10)' file
1
2
3
8
9
10
```

You can also avoid, hard-coding the line numbers by using the `-v` variable option,

```
awk -v start1=1 -v end1=3 -v start2=8 -v end2=10 '(NR>=start1 && NR<=end1) || (NR>=start2 && NR<=end2)' file
1
2
3
8
9
10
```